# getLogicalType() function of apache avro api returns null even if it is present

Tags: java, avro

I am using apache avro to and want get the logical type from my schema. I tried using the function `getLogicalType()` but it returns null. I don't understand what is wrong. My schema is as follows.

```
{
   "namespace": "example.avro",
   "type": "record",
   "name": "User",
   "fields": [
      {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int", "logicalType": "decimal", "precision": 2, "scale": "2"},
      {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
   ] 
 }
```

Following is the code where I am accessing the logicalType

```
    for(Schema.Field currField : schema.getFields()) {

       field = createFieldList(currField.name(), currField.schema().getType().toString(), currField.schema().getLogicalType());
       fields.add(field);
   }
```

Comment: As I wrote in comment to my answer you have loop for all fields and you defined *logicalType* only for second field, that's why getLogicalType() returns null, at least for first and third field. Try just printing result of getLogicalType for each field instead of using it in createFieldList().

Comment: No it prints null for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I think I found the answer. The way in which logical type was being declared was wrong.

Instead of

```
{
  "name": "favorite_number",
  "type": "int",
  "logicalType": "decimal", 
  "precision": 2,
  "scale": "2"
},
```

It should be

```
{
  "name": "favorite_number",
  "type": {
    "type": "int",
    "logicalType": "decimal",
    "precision": 2,
    "scale": "2"
  }
},
```

Now when I use getlogicalType() function it gives me the expected result

Comment: If this is the solution then I think you should get SchemaParseException and since you wrote that you didn't get it I think it may be a bug in avro. Anyway good that it works for you.

Comment: By the way you can access the logicalType in the first instance by using the function getObjectProps(). It returns a map from which you can access all the attributes of a field. As to if it should throw an exception, I don't really know if it should. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **parse** method which will set logicalType [here](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/17f2d75132021fafeca29edbdcade40df960fdc9/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.java#L1330) or **setLogicalType** which will initialize it [here](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/17f2d75132021fafeca29edbdcade40df960fdc9/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.java#L148). I don't have experienced with this library but basing on code I don't see other way.

Then this variable will be returned by [getLogicalType](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/17f2d75132021fafeca29edbdcade40df960fdc9/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.java#L144) method which you are using.

Comment: I used the parse method. Then i tried to access the fields and tried to get the logical type. But it returned null. currField.schema().getLogicalType(). Here currField is of type Field

Comment: Didn't you catch and ignored e.g. SchemaParseException?

Comment: Err. Why would it throw that exception. The above schema gets parsed.

Comment: I'm just giving an example how it could happen that null is returned. Anyway you wrote that you use it that way: currField.schema().getLogicalType(), in your case only one field has logicatType, so maybe you get null for first and third field only? Those are just loose thoughts again but we could be more precise if you could update your question with code where you are actually using this.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this can happen is when it is a union data type. Then the

```
currField.schema().getType()
```

become null, but instead you should investigate

```
currField.schema().getTypes()
```

which return a list of types. Iterate these types to find the one that has your logical type details.